# libGDX/Jython: TypeError: render() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: java, python, libgdx, jython, superclass

I'm making a Minesweeper clone called Poopsweeper (original, I know) with libGDX. I don't like Java so I'm using Jython (Python with Java compatibility).

I'm looking at the libGDX "Extended basic game" tutorial that teaches seperating a game into several screens (main menu, game, highscore, etc).

It says to do this in the main game class:

```
class PoopSweeper(Game):
    def create(self):
        self.batch = SpriteBatch()
        self.font = BitmapFont()
        self.screen = PlayScreen(self)

    def dispose(self):
        self.batch.dispose()
        self.font.dispose()

    def render(self):
        #Call superclass' render() method
```

And it's that render() superclass call I'm having trouble with.

I'm trying to do the Jython equivalent of this:

```
public void render() {
    super.render(); //important!
}
```

I've tried many ways:

```
super(Game, self).render()
Game.render(self)
self.super__render()
```

But all of these give this:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marvin\Dropbox\gaemz\PoopSweeper\PoopSweeper-Core\poopsweeper.py", line 29, in render
    self.super__render()
TypeError: render() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Here's my full code:
http://pastebin.com/cXgBc4XB

EDIT: Here's the javadocs of the class i'm trying to work with through Jython: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Game.html

EDIT2: I fixed it, the answer was something completely unrelated.

It was because I forgot to add a "delta" parameter to my SCREEN's render method. Still render(), but in a completely other class, which is why I got the two confused